# Battery notification, overriding do not disturb and playing alarm at night, though settings

Tags: notifications, battery, charging, battery-life

Many of us go to sleep with the phone next to the bed or on the tabletop next to the bed.

When at night, the phone enters the do not disturb mode, and we sleep.

However, it would be nice if the user could configure in the settings to be disturbed if the battery was running out.

This could be done, even overriding the notification mechanism and actually playing a special "night wake up" alarm.

This is important, because, in the morning, the phone needs to be charged.

It is important that this be configured in the settings, because sometimes you are on vacation, and you may be sleeping next to someone that may want to sleep and not be disturbed for no matter whatsoever.

Thanks.